# MSBuild Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject getting System.IO.PathTooLongException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a pretty big `ASP.NET` web application. I always publish to the File System through Visual Studio 2015 right clicking on my web project and selecting `Publish...`. This works perfect but now I'm trying to automate this process and I'm trying to make this publish process in the command line. This is what I'm running with the working directory set to the directory where my `.csproj` is located:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" MyProj.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="Properties\PublishProfiles\MCF New Arch.pubxml" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

The compilation seems to be working after some struggle but after that I get this error:

```
    "C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(CollectFilesFromProjectFolder target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProje
ctFolder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018: The "CollectFilesinFolder" task failed unexpectedly.\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\G
it-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too lo
ng. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 charac
ters.\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName()\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\M
CF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 ma
xPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathL
ength, Boolean expandShortPaths)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Gi
t-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String original
UserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)\r [C
:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption
 searchOption)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\S
ur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.CollectAllFiles(String
rootPath, DirectoryInfo dirinfo, Boolean recursive, List`1 result, Boolean defaultInclude, Regex[] fullPathMatchs, Rege
x[] relativePathMatchs, Regex[] excludeFullPathMatchs, Regex[] excludeRelativePathMatchs)\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-
Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CollectFilesinFolder.Execute()\r [C:\Users\A
ndres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExec
utionHost.Execute()\r [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\CollectFiles\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProject
Folder.targets(135,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext
() [C:\Users\Andres Torti\Git-Repos\MCF\Sur3D.App\MyProj.csproj]
```

I think it's getting a `System.IO.PathTooLongException` when running `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AllFilesInProjectFolder.targets`. I have seen people getting this problem in SO but when publishing from VS. In my case from VS the publish works perfectly but it fails when doing it from command line. Am I missing something?

Comment: does a simple web application have the same issue with msbuild tool? What's the result if you build and publish it through MSbuild Command Prompt for vs 2015? On the other hand, please copy solution folder to other disk (e.g. d:)

Comment: @s09 I created a new really simple Web App and I can publish it through the command line with no problems. I tried building through the `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015` and got exactly the same error.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, it seems that my publish trough command line is trying to publish EVERYTHING in the project folder and not only the included files in the project like the default Publish does. I had a `node_modules` folder with really long paths. Now I have to find a way to only copy the files included in the project

Comment: Which publish method you specified in pubxml? Provide details of pubxml. How do you add node_modules folder? Based on my test (install gulp, then it generates node_modules in specified folder), then build and publish through MSBuild, it doesn't include node_modules folder. Could you reproduce that issue with a new project? Provide detail steps.